# is it posible php and asp.net share the same server?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have have installed a software that came along with an ASP.NET
hosted in UltiDev Web Server Explorer a web application manager, its
database is .mdb, and I want to add some pages to it using PHP for an
additional features. And UltiDev can run only asp.net and I have no
time for now to study ASP. is there any other web application manager
that can run php and ISS together sharing the same .mdb database? I am
not interested in IIS right now.

Comment: Why no to IIS, You can run PHP and ASP.Net on IIS ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install PHP to run alongside an IIS installation with the Microsoft WebMatrix tool.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

On a sidenote, Helicon has a selection of PHP/Ruby/etc applications that can be easily deployed to an IIS installation via WebMatrix.

http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/gallery/

Comment: can i work on this without IIS? I want an application like UltiDev, i am planing to transfer those asp to a new web manager together with my php pages sharing the same database. thanks

Comment: It could be possible but I'm not sure as I haven't used that software before. If your reasoning for using a non IIS webserver is price you should check out the free versions of IIS (http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview).

Comment: you can try this http://www.truecafe.net/ to take a look at UltiDev. I will going to transfer those asp files to webmatrix together with my php files, if it runs. thanks for the effort friend.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can run PHP server on IIS but reverse is not so easy.

Goto this link and install this web platform installer. then you can access and manage your PHP files

http://php.iis.net/

you can easily manager like Apache server